# Script to deselect a link in selenium

Tags: hyperlink, deselect

I am using the script mentioned below to validate all the links in a web portal, but unfortunately there is a "logout" button link there due to which when I execute the script.

It gets logged out and hence the testing gets stopped. Can anyone help me to deselect that particular "logout" link and test all the other link?

Comment: for (WebElement e : linkElements) {
           linkTexts[i] = e.getText();
           i++;
       }
       
       
       for (String t : linkTexts) {
           driver.findElement(By.linkText(t)).click();
           if (driver.getTitle().equals(underConsTitle)) {
               System.out.println("\"" + t + "\""
                       + " is under construction.");
           } else {
               System.out.println("\"" + t + "\""
                       + " is working.");
           }
           driver.navigate().back();
       }
       driver.quit();
   }

Comment: please provide your comment as answer

Comment: I think that comment is the "script mentioned below". Though we cannot be certain which without confirmation.